# PHP - Check table to see if entry exists

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if a record exists in a table before adding it.
I've done some digging and this is what people keep coming back too:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = 'c7'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            // row not found, do stuff...
      } else {
       //row found, do other stuff...
      }
```

or some variation there of.

This logic is exactly what I need except for the fact that $result is never returning a positive result.

The record does exist and should return a positive result.

I also tried

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(email) FROM table WHERE email=$mail;";
$yesorno = mysqli_query($sql);
    echo $yesorno ;
```

as a test and the echo returns no value.

Comment: Don't use mysql_ they are old functions and removed in PHP7.  Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: You have a type %result instead of $result  ..

Comment: In my opinion, if you're just trying to validate if a row exists, you should be using `SELECT count(*)` and relying on MySQL to give you a 0 or 1.

Comment: Also consider using the `REPLACE INTO` syntax. Although it's somewhat "wasteful," it sure is convenient . . .

Comment: Can you show us some values from your database table? Especialy the row that suits your query.

Comment: you have a semicolon after $mail, issue #1. since email isn't an integer, you need to quote the text, issue #2.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check first if the query succeed running maybe there is a problem with it

```
$Query = "Select id from mytable where city = 'c7' ";
if($result = mysql_query($Query)) {
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {
// no rows found ;
} else {
// row exist ;
}
} else {
echo "Query failed ". $Query;
}
```